# qemu-kvm fail to boot Centos 5.3 after Kernel update at the host (feodra)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos5, fedora, qemu

After updating Fedora 18 to kernel 3.9.x (current 3.9.4), I can no longer boot my Centos 5 guest OS. When I try to boot, the process halt at start and the CPU core work at 100%.

If I boot Fedroa (host) using kernel 3.8.x everything work as expected.

[image: Guest console]

The command is:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-kvm -name MyGuestCentos5 -S -M pc-0.14 -cpu Nehalem,+rdtscp,+xtpr,
+tm2,+est,+vmx,+ds_cpl,+monitor,+pbe,+tm,+ht,+ss,+acpi,+ds,
+vme -enable-kvm -m 1024 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,
threads=1 -uuid 8502e6b9-993e-4e51-f3e4-613131379e51 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket
,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/MyGuestCentos.monitor,server,
nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,
mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -device piix3-usb-uhci,
id=usb,bus=pci.0,
addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/MyGuestCentos_centos5-clone.img,
if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk1,format=raw -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,
bus=pci.0,addr=0x6,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-disk1,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=22,
id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=23 -device virtio-net-pci,
netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:5f:13:a3,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,
id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,
chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,
id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5
```

Comment: I'd suggest managing your VMs with `libvirt` + `virt-manager` + `virt-viewer` to avoid the unnecessary work of typing such long commands and to try to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: dawud, I agree. I actually use virt-manager. this the process I get when issuing ps auxw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm facing same issue, and I just found this bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=967652

Workaround mentioned in bug works for me:

```
modprobe kvm_intel emulate_invalid_guest_state=0
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. Important note: it only worked after I first removed the module using: rmmod kvm_intel

Answer (score 2):

To update the accepted answer. Even in Fedora 20 with latest updates I had same issue running RHEL 5.3 guest.

To make the above workaround persistent through reboot put following in /etc/sysconfig/modules/kvm.modules

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -c /dev/kvm ]; then
    /usr/sbin/modprobe kvm_intel emulate_invalid_guest_state=0 > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Make the file executable by root:

```
chmod 700 /etc/sysconfig/modules/kvm.modules
```